# How to convert List<Object> to List<Dog> in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, list, object, casting

How to convert List to List. I tried doing this by

```
List<Object> obj = (some initialization)
List<Dog> dog =(List<Dog>)obj;
```

So this throws an error

```
ERROR: Cannot cast from List<Object> to List<Dog>
```

Where

```
 List<Object>
```

I get from the Hibernate Query

```
FROM DOG
```

Comment: If you are using hibernate use TypedQuery

Comment: Shoot the Dog. Becomes Object.

Comment: [casting between concrete types](http://bayou.io/draft/Wildcard_Case_Studies.html#Casting_Between_Concrete_Types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast works if you use a `List<?>` instead:

```
List<?> list = (some initialization);
List<Dog> dog = (List<Dog>)list;
```

If you got a `List<Object>` you still can cast it to a `List<Dog>`

```
List<Object> list = (some initialization);
List<Dog> dog = (List)list;
```

Of course this should only be done when you are sure that the list really contains `Dog` objects (e.g. as result value from your HQL query `FROM Dog`).

Comment: you'll probably get some warning from this one... Something like unchecked cast if i'm not mistaken

Comment: @Parker_Halo yes, and you also get the same warning when you cast Object to Dog

Comment: Are you sure about that? I just tried it in my Eclipse and it didn't give any warning...

Comment: It gave me warning but I think i should ignore it as i am fetching records from hibernate query.

Comment: @Parker_Halo you are right it does not

Answer (score 6):

Iterate over the `List<Object>` and cast every item explicitely

```
List<Dog> dog = new ArrayList<Dog>;
for (Object o : obj)
    dog.add((Dog) o);
```

Comment: Will it be efficient if would have to iterate over list of more than ten thousand items?

Comment: @SyedHassan i've just tried it with 20000 objects that are casted to `String` and it took 4 ms. So i think it should be fast enough ;)

Comment: if the list contains non-dogs this fails with a `ClassCastException`, else it would also be safe to simply cast the list (see my answer) without the need to create a copy of the list.

Comment: @wero That's true but the SyedHassan gets his objects from a Hibernate Query as he said so it should be fine!

Comment: you can also create a readonly wrapper `List<Dog>`, which checks the type during `get()`. This is quite easy by subclassing `AbstractList`